# How the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function do something in UITableViewController class

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a view and have navigationController...

and a rightBarButtonItem on it ,

then click-->use popoverController show the tableViewController's view... 
tableView have 3 cells----like A,B,C

and i want to know ,
in the table list, different textlabel go　to　different view，　cell A goto View_A,cell B goto View_B....
I need to put the view in the `navigationController`...

But it doesn't work in the tableViewController's class,when i write the code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.....

I try

```
[ self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[ self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[ self.view.superview.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

**I dont know how to do something outside when I click the tableView's cell,especially how to get the `navigationController`.....**

Answer (score 0):

As you are in the popview and that view is just dismissed after taping on the cell of the tableView the `self` is referred to the popupView it doesn't work. 
You must have to use `delegate` to do the work done. Please refer to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307)Link for reference

Comment: if i use self.popoverController.delegate = self; does it help?

Comment: yes, as per my knowledge it will help you to call popoverController's delegate methos

Comment: oh　i　see，　i just add UINavigationController　value to the tableViewController.. It can help....